# error: no match for ‘operator ==’ (operand types are ‘const class’ and ‘const class’) if (object1 == object2)

Tags: c++

I'm having some errors with my code, which I don't know how to solve.
The error is:

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const Secuencia’ and const Secuencia’)
if (sec1 == sec2)

note: candidate: ‘bool Secuencia::operator==(const Secuencia&)’ 
bool operator == (const Secuencia & otro);

note: passing ‘const Secuencia*’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers
```

In my .h I have:

```
bool operator == (const Secuencia & other);
```

And in my .cpp:

```
bool Secuencia :: operator == (const Secuencia & other){

    bool same = (used == other.used && capacity == other.capacity ? true:false);

    if(same == true){

        for(int i = 0; i < used && same == true; i++){
            if(info[i] != otro.info[i])
                same = false;
        }

    }

    return (same);
}
```

Comment: Your operator shall be a const method : bool operator == (const Secuencia & other) const;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define `operator ==` as a member function, it shoud be `const`:

```
       bool operator == (const Secuencia & other) const;
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realised it

Comment: Even the compiler does not catch it!?